# Creating an XML document with more than 1 child element with XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd, altova

I have come with an xml schema to create an xml document. The root node is **movies**. Now this root element has child elements called **movie** which contains other elements of a string type and every movie also has about three or four attributes.
However after linking my XML document with the schema I am only able to create ONE movie node and no more than that. Here is my xml schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--root element movies --> 
<xsd:element name="movies">
    <xsd:complexType >
        <xsd:all >
            <xsd:element name="movie">
                <xsd:complexType >
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <!--Elements under each movie-->
                        <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="writer" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="producer" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="director" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <!--Not sure the number of actors a movie can have -->
                        <xsd:element name="actor" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        <xsd:element name="poster" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="comments" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="type" use="required">
                        <!--attribute type with its options -->
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:enumeration value="drama"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="comedy"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="adventure"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="sci-fi"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="mystery"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="horror"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="romance"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="documentary"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                    <xsd:attribute name="rating" use="required">
                        <!--attribute rating with its options -->
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:enumeration value="G"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="PG"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="PG-13"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="X"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="ua"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                    <xsd:attribute name="review" use="optional">
                        <!--attribute review with its options -->
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="3"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="4"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="5"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                    <xsd:attribute name="year" use="optional">
                        <!--attribute year -->
                    </xsd:attribute>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Can someone help finding my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In order to allow a sequence of more than one `movie` within `movies`:

(1) Change `xsd:all` to `xsd:sequence`.

(2) Change

```
    <xsd:element name="movie">
```

to

```
    <xsd:element name="movie" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

Comment: Works,thanks i'm a newbie to XML I only deal with it when I am doing Android. @kjhughes. whats the difference between xsd:all and xsd:sequence ?

Comment: @Manny264, see [Difference between <xsd:all> and <xsd:sequence> in schema definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16101488/290085)