# When adding Schema to XmlSchemaSet, I get an exception

Tags: c#, xsd

I have this XSD I made

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xsd:complexType name="FunnyType">
        <xsd:element name="Prueba1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Prueba2" type="xsd:int"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="Funnys">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="funny" type="FunnyType" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Which gives me a *System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:element' is invalid in this context.* (not the exact error, I translated it from spanish).

I have gone up and down everywhere (here, asking colleagues, etc) and made changes to the file, yet I cannot find the error.

What am I lacking here that makes c# throw an exception?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="FunnyType">
  <xsd:element name="Prueba1" type="xsd:string" />
  <xsd:element name="Prueba2" type="xsd:int" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

You have to begin the complexType with one of the 3 compositors: `xsd:sequence`, `xsd:all` or `xsd:choice`:

For example:

```
<xsd:complexType name="FunnyType">
  <!-- Can also be xsd:all or xsd:choice -->
  <xsd:sequence> 
    <xsd:element name="Prueba1" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:element name="Prueba2" type="xsd:int" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

You need to decide which one to use that best suits what your complex type is meant to model.

Comment: yes, I fixed it on friday, but I forgot to answer here.

I really appreciate it and I'll mark the answer as valid, since it is. Not only for me, but for anyone else.

In my case, since it needs all the elements, I used 'sequence'. As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101488/difference-between-xsdall-and-xsdsequence-in-schema-definition), seems like the main difference between all and sequence is wether unordered or ordered elements are required.

I also added minOccurs=1 and maxOccurs=1, since they are mandatory but only 1 of each must be contained