# How to use sequence and non sequence childs in xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

**1. I have a well-formed xml as follows**

```
<graph>
    <id>g0</id>
    <name>test</name>
    <nodes>
        <node>
            <id>a</id>
            <name>xxxx</name>
        </node>
        <node>
            <id>e</id>
            <name>xxxx</name>
        </node>
    </nodes>
    <edges>
        <node>
            <id>e1</id>
            <from>a</from>
            <to>e</to>
        </node>
    </edges>
</graph>
```

**2. My logic, and XSD attempt to implement it**

I am trying to define a schema for my xml with the role that all elements should come in order  after each other but id and name can be in any order as far as they are there
here is my sechema

```
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="graph" type="AType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="AType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="nodes"  minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="node" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="id"/>
                                <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="name"/>
                                <xsd:any minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

so as you can see here my

```
    <id>g0</id>
<name>test</name>
```

is also part of the sequence and they are forced to follow the order but I do not want any order on these two as far as they are there
any suggestion?

Note: please note I know all will mean order does not matter but my issue is how I can use both all and seuqence together complex type?

**3. XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.**

I am using XSD processor ... and its conformance with the XSD standards ...

Comment: Your XML sample is not well-formed.

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete XSD that tried to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101488/difference-between-xsdall-and-xsdsequence-in-schema-definition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between <xsd:all> and <xsd:sequence> in schema definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101488/difference-between-xsdall-and-xsdsequence-in-schema-definition)

Comment: Not really or maybe I do not know how to use it. How can I have both sequence and all in a complex type together?

Comment: Please provide ##1-3 for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: added an example if I got your point

Comment: so lets say edges should come after nodes but any other elements can come in any order including id name in graph or id name in nodes or id from to in edges

Comment: You need XSD 1.1, and its **openContent** functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix xs:all and xs:sequence in the same content model, but you can define a sequence that allows either

```
id, name, nodes, edges
```

or

```
name, id, nodes, edges
```

by making the content model

```
sequence
   choice
      sequence
         id
         name
      sequence
         name
         id
   nodes
   edges
```

Comment: Actually this is smart let me try and get back with answer here

Comment: in between I am stuck with this one I appreciate your help if you if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77327983/validate-xml-in-a-way-that-a-value-in-a-node-in-edge-should-be-present-in-the-no