# validate xml in a way that a value in a node in edge should be present in the nodes > node otherwise that is not valid

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing

I have a scenario where I need to validate xml in a way that a value in a node in edge should be present in the nodes > node otherwise that is not valid

```
<graph>
   <nodes>
     <node>
       <id>1</id>
     </node>
   <nodes>
   <edges>
     <from> 1 </from>
     <to> 4 </to> 
   </edges>
   <name>test</name>
```

so the above is invalid as there is a  to 4 which is not present in nodes > node
is it possible to do this sort of validation in xsd:schema ?

Update for more clarification:
so this is a valid graph

```
<graph>
   <nodes>
     <node>
       <id>1</id>
     </node>
     <node>
       <id>4</id>
     </node>
   <nodes>
   <edges>
     <from> 1 </from>
     <to> 4 </to> 
   </edges>
   <name>test</name>
```

because both nodes 1 and 4 exists in nodes section so they can be used in edges 
however here

```
  <graph>
       <nodes>
         <node>
           <id>1</id>
         </node>
       <nodes>
       <edges>
         <from> 1 </from>
         <to> 4 </to> 
       </edges>
       <name>test</name>
</graph>
```

4 is not defined in nodes section so should be validated as  invalid

here is my xml:

```
<graph>
    <id>g0</id>
    <name>test</name>
    <nodes>
        <node>
            <id>a</id>
            <name>a name</name>
        </node>
    </nodes>
    <edges>
        <node>
            <id>e1</id>
            <from>a</from>
            <to>b</to>
            <cost>42</cost>
        </node>
        <node>
            <id>e5</id>
            <from>a</from>
            <to>c</to>
            <cost>0.42</cost>
        </node>
    </edges>
</graph>
```

(note not sure if it matters or not but I use lxml Pyhton library for validation)

Comment: It is not clear what you need. Please edit your question, and provide some additional info.

Comment: Sure and thanks for the suggestion. Updated it

Comment: XSD 1.1 can do it

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete XSD that tried to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

Comment: I added the full xml I am trying to validate. The problem is I am not sure if it is even possible have no clue on this specific constraint. I know there is a keyref but it only supports  attributes and it is not about the value/text dependencies

Comment: What about #3? *(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.*